# How user can select css style?

Tags: css, prestashop

I start to make an online shopping site with prestashop. On my product-list pages I want to let users to choose gridview column number as 3 or 4. Should I do this with css switch method? Or is there another method?

Comment: I don't know what a css switch method is, but if you mean "should I change styles using javascript", yes that is a good idea.

Comment: i don't think someone will be able to help you since you didn't even tried to do something for this. If i'm wrong please include some code of your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a class to the body depending on their settings. You can then have rules separated by this class, and by what is common to them both

HTML

```
...
<body class="columns-3">
<!-- change the class using javascript, or php session for example -->
...
```

CSS

```
.col{
  /* rules for `.col` common to both */
}

.column-3 .col{
  /* rules for `.col` when in three column mode */
}

.column-4 .col{
  /* rules for `.col` when in four column mode */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do as billy moon mentions, and use jquery to perform the switch , like with     `$("body").addClass("column-4");`